# How to append values to an array in C and calculating the shortest distance between two points

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, dynamic-arrays

I need help on making a program that will count the shortest distance between two places that are arranged in a circular pattern I need to count the distance between first and first, first and second and so on keeping in mind I can go the other way around if the distance is shorter and place the results in a matrix equal to the length of the array that we have inputted at the beginning of the program, so the output should look something like this:
input:

```
Array length=5
Array elements:2 3 4 1 1
```

so the output should look like this:

```
2 3 4 1 1
0 2 5 2 1
2 0 3 4 3
5 3 0 4 5
2 4 4 0 1
1 3 5 1 0
```

The code that I wrote only gets user input for array length and elements and outputs the first line which is the elements of an array that we have gotten from the user input. So my question is how to get that shortest way for every distance and append those values to the matrix.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int* ptr;
    int l,n, i, m, x,y,s,j,t;
    int **p;

    scanf("%d", &l);

    ptr = (int*)malloc(l * sizeof(int));

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }
    else {

        for (i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        {
            scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
            if(ptr[i]<0)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", ptr[i]);
        }
    }

    n=l;
    m=l;

    while(m>0 && n>0){
        p= malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
        for (i=0;i<m;i++){
            p[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                x=0;
                y=0;
                for (t = 0; t < j; t++) {
                    x  = +ptr[t];
                }
                for (t = n; t >j; t--) {
                    y = +ptr[t];
                }
                if (x > y) {
                    s = y;
                } else {
                    s = x;
                }
                p[i][j]=s;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("%d", p[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `m` and `n` variables if they're just copies of `l`?

Comment: `x  = +ptr[t];` should be `x += ptr[t]`.

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm going to fix it, but I need more help with the code that calculates the shortest distance and the one that puts the values into the array if you can tell me what I did wrong or add something it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by calculating distance.

Comment: Why is the distance between the first and second element 2, not 1?

Comment: Why are you calculating sums of the array elements before and after j?

Comment: 1.Array length resembles the number of cities the array elements resemble the distance between them, 
2.the first number from the array is from first to the second city and so on and since they are in a circle form the last number resembles the distance between the 5th and first city.
3. because I need to find the shortest path and use it I don't know if that code is good but if you can help me I would greatly appreciate it.